# Not getting the data from database

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, background-task

This is my MainActivity.java. I am trying to display it in mainactivity but I am not able to fetch the data.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FloatingActionButton f;
    ListView list;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask( this);
    backgroundTask.execute("get_info");
    f=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fb);
    f.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent a=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(a);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up, R.anim.push_down);
        }
       });

       }

       }
```

This is BackgroundTask:

```
    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Listitems,String> {
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    Context ctx;
    Adapter adapter;
    Activity activity;
    ListView listView;

    BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
    {
    this.ctx=  ctx;
    activity =(Activity)ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String method=params[0];
    DatabaseHelper databasehelper =new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
    if(method.equals("add_info")){
        String name=params[1];
        String time=params[2];
        String date=params[3];
        SQLiteDatabase db = databasehelper.getWritableDatabase();
        databasehelper.insertData(db,name,time,date);
        return "Inserted....";
       }
       else if(method.equals("get_info"))
       {
        listView=(ListView)activity.findViewById(R.id.hlist);
        Cursor cursor =databasehelper.getalldata();
        adapter =new Adapter(ctx,R.layout.adapter_layout);
        String id;
        String name;
        String time;
        String date;

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            id=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.S1));
            name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.S2));
            time=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.S3));
            date=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.S4));
            Listitems list= new Listitems(id,name,time,date);
            publishProgress(list);
        }

        }
        return "get_info";

       }



      @Override
     protected void onProgressUpdate(Listitems... values) {
     adapter.add(values[0]);

     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     if(result.equals("get_info")){
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }
      else {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }


    }
    }
```

This is my DatabaseHelper.java:

```
    package com.example.hems.todolist;


     public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Notes.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Notes";
    public static final String S1 = "ID";
    public static final String S2 = "Task_Name";
    public static final String S3 ="Task_Time";
    public  static final String S4 ="Task_Date";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }


   @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("Create Table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + S1 + " integer primary         key AUTOINCREMENT," + S2 + " text," + S3 + " time," + S4 + " date)");
    Log.d("Database Operations","Table Inserted Successfully");

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)             {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);


    }
    public long insertData(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String time, String date) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(S2, name);
    contentValues.put(S3, time);
    contentValues.put(S4, date);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    Log.d("Database Operations","Inserted Successfully");
    return result ;
    }

    public Cursor getalldata( ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(" select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;


    }



    }
```

Listitems.java:

```
  public class Listitems {
  private String id,name;
  private String time;
  private String date;

   public Listitems(String id, String name, String time, String date){
    this.setId(id);
    this.setName(name);
    this.setTime(time);
    this.setDate(date);
   }

   public String getId() {

    return id;
   }

   public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
   }

   public String getName() {
    return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

   public String getTime() {
    return time;
   }

   public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
   }

   public String getDate() {
    return date;
   }

   public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
   }
   }
```

Adapter.java:

```
    public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list =new ArrayList();
    public Adapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
    }


   public void add(Listitems object) {
    list.add(object);
    super.add(object);
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
    }


   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
   }


   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ListitemsHolder listitemsHolder;
    if (row == null) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)    this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, parent, false);
        listitemsHolder = new ListitemsHolder();
        listitemsHolder.h1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.r1);
        listitemsHolder.h2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.r2);
        listitemsHolder.h3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.r3);
        listitemsHolder.h4 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.r4);
        row.setTag(listitemsHolder);
       } 
       else {
        listitemsHolder=(ListitemsHolder)row.getTag();
      }
    Listitems listitems=(Listitems)getItem(position);
    listitemsHolder.h1.setText(listitems.getId());
    listitemsHolder.h2.setText(listitems.getName());
    listitemsHolder.h3.setText(listitems.getTime());
    listitemsHolder.h4.setText(listitems.getDate());
    return row;
   }
   static class ListitemsHolder{
    TextView h1, h2,h3,h4;
   }
   }
```

iam getting the layout of listview but not the data i entered it is blank..so help me to get the data.and i am entering the data in second activity i think you don't need that!!

Comment: Did you use run time permissions.they are necessity in the android phones with os later than or equal to marshmallow.

Comment: Please help me guys